# Select Records With a Count of greater than 1 Where a field has multiple values

Tags: sql, db2

I'm having an issue trying to select records where there are different values for the field (invH.CODE) which is a VARCHAR type.  For example, if there are 2 different codes with values such as "PLCH" and "ABCD".  Below is the sql I have so far:

```
SELECT invH.INVOICE_NO
FROM SCHEMA.INVOICE_H invH
WHERE invH.STATUS = 'X'
GROUP BY invH.INVOICE_NO
HAVING COUNT (DISTINCT invH.CODE) > 1
```

I'm trying to select records where there is an instance in which two different values for that field are present (there can be multiple values for this field in one record).  I'm unsure of how to get that syntactically.  Please let me know of any efficient way of getting this.

I'm using DB2/AIX64 Version 9.5.3.

Comment: You may want to add some sample data to your question. Also indicate your DB2 version and platform.

Comment: Is the `status` filter part of the problem? This ought to work if indeed you can have multiple rows with the same `INVOICE_NO`. It's unclear what you meant when you said "this field in one record" though.

Comment: Sometimes it helps to show example input data and desired results from that data. This can clarify potential ambiguity of interpreting your words by showing each scenario of input & what happens as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I think , if you use the self joins between the table to get the values , 
otherwise you need to use subquery to solve it . 
In case of join I think below query should work

```
SELECT DISTINCT invH1.INVOICE_NO
FROM SCHEMA.INVOICE_H invH1 , SCHEMA.INVOICE_H invH2
WHERE invH1.STATUS = invH2.STATUS
and invH1.INVOICE_NO = invH2.INVOICE_NO
and invH1.STATUS = 'X'
and invH1.CODE <> invH2.CODE
```

Comment: @shawnt00 My condition also includes `invH1.STATUS = invH2.STATUS` which makes other also have `STATUS='X'`

Comment: I noticed the extra condition and deleted the comment. But you might also notice that two mismatched codes would produce two results in the output and similarly three mismatched results would end up with six. `SELECT DISTINCT` would likely be required to address that problem.